# Grabbing lines after a matched line in perl

Tags: perl

How do I access all lines after the line on which a pattern matched occur
For example

> BCDA
>   ABCD
>   AAAABBBBCCCCDDD
>   AAAAAABBBBBBCCC
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAA

So basically after the pattern ABCD is matched i want to process all the lines after it.Put it in an array.So do a pattern match only once .

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Put **what** into an array? Match **what** pattern only once?

Comment: so i want to process the lines after the pattern has been matched.So in an array i would want to put the lines after ABCD.I want to the loop over each line and then do some comparison.For that i would want to store all the lines AFTER the matched pattern in order to store them.

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest example I can think of for what it sounds like you are looking for. 
It puts "all the lines after " the line that matched into an array.

```
my @lines;
while ( <$in> ) { 
    next unless m/ABCD/;
    # in an list context, this will slurp the rest of the file.
    @lines = <$in>;
}
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity and "my thoughts exactly". Though you should make the regex `/^ABCD$/`, or similarly strict.

Comment: so what you have written above,will it also consider the line ABCD?

Comment: It will take all the lines in the file *after* ABCD is found, but not the ABCD line itself.

Comment: Thanks, TLP. @kunal, the marker line is already consumed by the iterator in the while, so all that's left is the lines afterward, and copying a file iterator to an array, slurps in all those lines.

Comment: @TLP. i want to include the line ABCD too...is there a way? Its liek i have to search for a particular string and when that string occurs,start processing(storing) the lines from the 1st occurance of that string

Comment: @kunal `@lines = ( $_, <$in> )` will do that.

Answer (score 3):

A  bit unclear, but is this what you are after?

The [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) is ideal for this sort of task:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @array;

while (<DATA>)  {
  push @array, $_ if /ABCD/ .. 0
}
shift(@array);

print @array;

__DATA__
BCDA
ABCD
AAAABBBBCCCCDDD
AAAAAABBBBBBCCC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Outputs:

```
AAAABBBBCCCCDDD
AAAAAABBBBBBCCC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: I didn't know you could put the data at the end of the same file that the Perl code is in! Thanks Fredrik.

Comment: well yes this is what i am after though i dont want to print the lines but store it in an array.but yes you are right,this is what i am looking for.

Comment: What did you have in mind by putting `eof()` inside a pattern match? Better would be `push @array, $_ if /ABCD/ .. 0`. Also you can print the array directly: `print @array`.

Comment: @FMc - for the eof() part I blame temporal insanity; for the print part, it was for clarity, since I expected that the OP would like to do something with the content in the array (updated answer). Thanks!

Comment: Note that using 0 there could cause unfortunate behaviour if a data line contains a 0 character - probably better to use undef instead.